# Java swing, adding array list to a component

Tags: java, swing

I wanna do something like

```
ArrayList<String> users;
JPanel panel;

panel.add(users);
```

But this is not legal since JPanel can't take arraylists or strings, but must take a component instead. So I tried to find out if there is a component that will take a string, or even better, an arraylist. Is this possible, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How the `ArrayList` will look like as a GUI?... :/

Comment: The arrylist will just contain a list of the users in the chat room

Comment: "So I tried to find out if there is a component that will take a string" [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)? What kind of information were you planning to display and in what format?

Comment: @user1960836 Then you don't need to add it to the `JPanel`, you should add the users to some `JTextArea` instead.

Comment: @user1960836 wrote `The arrylist will just contain a list of the users in the chat room` <> ??? JList, with additional column(s) <> JTable ???

Comment: @mKorbel LOL we all missed that